# Mocha list only skipped tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have hundreds of tests in mocha, tens of which are being skipped.

I would like to run the suite, but only listing the skipped ones, so I can address them.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this? There does not seem to be a command line flag

Comment: have you tried `--grep ^skip` but would work if `.skip('skip some test')`

Comment: yeah I figured it would need to be some workaround like that. thanks anyway. Guess I can just search in text editor for ".skip" in test folder and address them that way. Was just hoping for a nice summary :)

Answer (score 3):

Mocha comes with a built-in JSON reporter. The output JSON lists all the skipped test cases. For example

```
mocha -R JSON > test-report.json
```

Here the test-report.json file should have the following structure.

```
{
    stats: {...},
    tests: [...],
    pending: [...],
    failures: [...],
    passes: [...]
}
```

The "pending" key should have all the skipped test cases.